# Rails route with resources :address - Singular & Plural

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a route for addresses:

```
  namespace :carts do
    resources :address
```

Yet it generates a mispelling for the new path, `addres`. Is this a bug in Rails 3.2.14?

```
              carts_address GET    /carts/address(.:format)                                             refinery/carts/address#index
                            POST   /carts/address(.:format)                                             refinery/carts/address#create
           new_carts_addres GET    /carts/address/new(.:format)                                         refinery/carts/address#new
          edit_carts_addres GET    /carts/address/:id/edit(.:format)                                    refinery/carts/address#edit
               carts_addres GET    /carts/address/:id(.:format)                                         refinery/carts/address#show
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must name your route according to your controller's name. And both of them must be plural form

So the correct route for addresses is: `resources :addresses`, knowing that your controller must be `AddressesController`

More info on routing: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Oops, added that and it worked `new_carts_address GET    /carts/addresses/new(.:format)                                       refinery/carts/addr`. I wish Rails would make everything singular.