# ruby on rails 5.2 --"form for" couldn't update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, updates, form-for

I used form_for to create a form , it could create, but not update, the code like this:

```
def create
  @message=Message.new(message_params)
  if @message.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def edit
    @message=Message.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @message=Message.find(params[:id])
    if @message.update(message_params)
        redirect_to message_path(@message)
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

I followed the tutorial every step, they can do it , but i can't. it always show:

```
 No route matches [POST] "/message/4/edit"
```

I don't know why it couldn't direct to update path? 
thanks

routes:

```
resources :message
```

form view:

```
<h1>Edit</h1>
<%= form_for :message do |a| %>
<p>
<%= a.label :name %><br>
<%= a.text_field :name %>
</p>

<p>
 <%= a.label :description %><br>
 <%= a.text_area :description %>
</p>
<%=a.submit "update"%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please, add code from routes.rb and your form code

Comment: my form is like above. Some tutorial said rails will know when to use post or patch by clicking the same submit button. they said if rails couldn't find record in model, it will use "post" to create; but when it found an old record in model, it will use "patch or put" to update automatically. is that right? thanks.

Comment: @JuniorChung in your `routes.rb`, it's plural `resources :messages`

Comment: @sovalina, does it matter? I'm not quite sure,I thought it's just a name, it could be any name, right?

Comment: @JuniorChung If you want to user your `message` resource as singular then use the `resource` method singular instead : `resource :message`. I share you the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33258203/9541423) which explains well the difference between singular and plural resources. Mix naming resource singular/plural problem was also solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532388/rails-route-with-resources-address-singular-plural)

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that there is something wrong with your form in your view.

If you look at what is created by `resources :messages` in a `routes.rb`:

[image]

You can see that the controller action `update` should not be a POST method - it should be PATCH or PUT.

I would recommend reading [this great article Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) - when you are finished with that, i bet you can figure out what is wrong with your form.

Best of luck

Comment: Thanks Peter, I am also confused about this. I used the same form to create, once click submit button, it can post to model; but when I used it to update, it didn't use Patch or put method, but I find the tutorial on youtube, they did the same, and it could use patch or put to update automatically. I am not sure if the version problem or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote in the comment: "Some tutorial said rails will know when to use post or patch by clicking the same submit button. They said if rails couldn't find record in model, it will use "post" to create; but when it found an old record in model, it will use "patch or put" to update automatically".

And this is correct.

But Rails need something to know which record to update (record id, for example). You have `<%= form_for :message do |a| %>` in the form. Here is no info about which record to update. It should be

```
<%= form_for @message do |a| %>
```

Note `@`- this is the instance variable from the controller edit action `@message = Message.find(params[:id])`, and this is the particular message with id.

If you use it you can write only one form for create and update actions, it will work automagically - just get @message from new/edit action.

You can read more about it in [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#relying-on-record-identification)

Comment: Thanks Vasilisa,
I've solved it by using the long style like here:

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the long-style, but the short-style still doesn't work, i have no idea. Anyway, thanks you guys a lot.

```
## Creating a new article
# long-style:
form_for(@article, url: articles_path)
# same thing, short-style (record identification gets used):
form_for(@article)

## Editing an existing article
# long-style:
form_for(@article, url: article_path(@article), html: {method: 
"patch"})
# short-style:
form_for(@article)
```